# Conditional template values in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

We want to have a single drop down for parameter X and we wish to deduce the other parameters say Y and Y from the selected X value.

Is it possible in Grafana?

Did not find much content around it

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use template variables within the query field of another template variable via `$Variable_name`, similarly to how you reference them in queries.

The exact format depends on the data-source but with influxDB it would look something like this.

- First variable:

  - Name: `Network`
  - Query: `SHOW TAG VALUES FROM readings WITH KEY = "network"`
- Second variable:

  - Name: `Device`
  - Query: `SHOW TAG VALUES FROM readings WITH KEY = "device" where "network" = $Network`

Basically, show a list of all networks in the first dropdown, and in the second dropdown only show devices that belong to the selected network. The second dropdown is updated dynamically.